# Is QueryList.find more fast than QueryList.toArray[x] angular 2

Tags: angular, time-complexity

I was wondering about QueryList data structure from angular 2.

And I have 2 possibilities to get element form my this.circle QueryList :

First One :

```
let cir = this.circles.find( el => (el.rowNumber == row && el.colNumber == column));
```

Second One :

```
let cir:ColOperations = this.circles.toArray()[row*this.colsNumber + column];
```

Maybe `.toArray` to the same computing like `.find` or even worse.

Which solution is faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryList<T>` is essentially a wrapper around an array of some type `T`, in fact, the implementation of `QueryList<T>` has a private property called `_results` that is an array of type `T`, so both approaches you have there are identical, but the second one is redundant and "bad" (Note the quotes), because `QueryList.toArray` **has to make a copy** of the `_results` array and return it to the caller. Most of the functions on `QueryList` just delegate to the underlying array. So, stick to your first one. You only need to call `QueryList.toArray` if you need to mutate the array since `QueryList` is immutable. For your convenience, [here's the link to the source code for QueryList.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/core/src/linker/query_list.ts). Look at line 40 and line 90